# Rails date_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've a form input like this

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dob %>
    <%= f.date_field :dob %>
</div>
```

so in my migration file.. should i save it as a string ?

```
def change
  t.string :dob
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add it as a `date` column

```
def change
   t.date :dob
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime` or `date` instead of string. This way you can query on that column if needed

```
def change
  add_column :table_name, :dob, datetime
end
```

OR

```
create_table(:table_name) do |t|
  t.datetime :dob
end
```